# OfficeJs Addin - Get manifest fields

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

Developing an outlook addin I seach for a way to read the manifest fields, in particular the extension id via the provided office-js api.

Is there any way to read the properties defined in the addin manifest with the office js api?

Answer (score 1):

`OfficeJS` doesn't provide anything for that.

If you host the manifest file on the web server somewhere you could read the content as any other file from the server and parse it on your own.

Feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when the dev team go through the planning process. Use the github label: “Type: product feature request” at https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions .

Comment: This is basically right, but strictly speaking it is a _copy_ of the manifest that you host on a web server. The original manifest file is not published to a place where it has an HTTPS URL that can be known to the add-in at runtime. For example, if you deploy to AppSource or by Centralized Deployment. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/publish for all the deployment options.

Comment: @RickKirkham I've clearly states that `OfficeJS` doesn't provide anything for that.

Comment: I agree with the answer in your first paragraph. That's why I voted it up. I just want to clarify the workaround in your second paragraph. Many beginners coming to Office Add-in development mistakenly believe that the manifest gets deployed to the web app along with the HTML and JavaScript files. I'm afraid that without clarification, you second paragraph might encourage that misunderstanding. Thanks for all the great work you do on Stack of Office Add-ins!

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the feature to read manifest items via Office-Js APIs, you requested, is not a part of the product.

We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [Tech Community Page](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform). Please submit your request there and choose the appropriate label(s). Feature requests on Tech Community are considered when we go through our planning process.